# Split Array using Null separator

Tags: javascript

Is there a method to split an array into arrays that dont contain null values using javascript (without developing a function)...

Here is an example of what I want have :

input :

```
var a = [1, 2, 3, null, 2, null,null, 4]
```

output :

```
[[1, 2, 3], [2], [4]]
```

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried to loop over array and create sub arrays?

Comment: I know I can, but I'm asking if there is a ready method for use ... without developing a function

Comment: Looping is done in about 3 lines and there's no reason there would be a generic solution to this very specific problem.

Comment: Ok, that's fine so ... (the split function for strings is awesome -- I hoped there is one for arrays) ... Thank you

Comment: A loop is the best you can do

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To the question

*"Is there a ready to use function to build my array"*,

the answer is

"**No**, because your need is too specific".

But it's not so hard to do it yourself. Here's a solution (I took a less trivial input with `null` at ends and consecutive `null` to be more demonstrative):

```js
var a = [null, 1, 2, 3, null, 2, null, null, 4, null];
var b = []; // result
for (var arr, i=0; i<a.length; i++) {
  if (a[i]===null) {
    arr=null;
  } else {
    if (!arr) b.push(arr=[]);
    arr.push(a[i]);
  }
}
document.body.textContent = JSON.stringify(b); // just print the result
```

As you can see, there's nothing pretty or magical, just a tedious iteration.

Comment: Yes, Thanks Denys, this works .. but my question is about if there is a method ready for use or not ... However I know that we can develop a function :) ... thank you for your help

Comment: Thank you Denys .. I took your answer as the accepted one :)

Comment: using `slice` would be faster I think

Comment: @CodeiSir depending on the input, it would probably be faster, yes, but `push` is already fast (especially on homogeneous arrays) so I doubt it really matters (but I agree it could be faster).

Answer (score 2):

You can use `reduce`:

```
[1, 2, 3, null, 2, null, 4].reduce(function(arr, val) {
  if(val === null) arr.push([]);
  else arr[arr.length-1].push(val);
  return arr;
}, [[]]);
```

Comment: that's the general idea but this doesn't handle painful cases like a null at the begining or two consecutive null.

Comment: @DenysSéguret `"_".split("_")` is `["",""]`. Similarly, my code returns `[ [],[] ]` for `[null]`.

Comment: Also, this function is not good, for example if I have in input : [1, 2, 3, null, 2, null,null,null, 4]

Comment: @taboubim If that's the case, you need to make your question clearer about possible inputs and expected outputs, though if you do, you may invalidate this answer.  A better approach may be to take this as an answer to the question asked, and see if you can tweak it to suit your actual needs.

Comment: @DenysSéguret `"123_2___4".split("_")` is `["123","2","","","4"]`. Similarly, my code returns `[[1,2,3],[2],[],[],[4]]` for `[1,2,3,null,2,null,null,null,4]`.

Comment: The comment above was supposed to be a reply to taboubim, not DenysSéguret.

Answer (score 1):

There is no function in the library which does what you expect. But if you approach it simply, you can use the next approach

```
var a = [1, 2, 3, null, 2, null, 4]
var result = [], temp = [];

for(var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    if (a[i] === null) {
        if (temp.length == 0) continue;
        result.push(temp);
        temp = [];
    }
    else {
        temp.push(a[i]);
    }
}
if (temp.length != 0) result.push(temp);
// use your result, it gives [[1, 2, 3], [2], [4]]
```

i have added some functionalities to prevent problems with double `null`, starting `null` and ending `null`. The next step is just wrapping the above snippet in a function, using `a` as argument and `result` as return value. This even handles `a = []` without problems too.

Answer (score 0):

I needed this function, and using .push() isn't going to be fast enough. Here's one using .slice(), as coderPi pointed out.

```js
function split(arr, separator = null) {
  const chunks = [];
  let i = 0, j = 0;
  while (j++ < arr.length) {
    let nextIndex = arr.indexOf(separator, i);
    if (nextIndex === -1) {
      chunks.push(arr.slice(i, arr.length));
      return chunks;
    } else if (nextIndex !== i) {
      chunks.push(arr.slice(i, nextIndex));
    }
    i = nextIndex + 1;
  }
  return chunks;
}

// example:

const myChucks = split([1, 2, 3, null, 2, null, null, 4]);

// returns: [[1,2,3],[2],[4]]

document.write(JSON.stringify(myChucks))
```